# How to generate multiple SVG's in a Meteor.js #each wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, templates, d3.js, meteor

Hi there I currently have a template helper that returns me an array with various values used to generate different rows in a table in my HTML.

```
<template name="stop">  
   {{#each thumb}}

  <tr>
    <td>
       <h2> Do you like this product? </h2>
       <h2>{{text}}</h2>
      <svg id="donutChart">  </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

It also contains a svg tag which I also want to generate a graph for each element generated as a table row and this is what the template helper looks like.

```
 Template.stop.helpers({
        'thumb': function(data) {
            var result = tweetImages.findOne();
            var newResult = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                newResult[i] = {
                    data: result.data[i],
                    text: result.text[i]
                };
            }
            console.log(newResult)
            return newResult;
        }
```

I'm trying to create a pie reactive pie chart for each element in the table however I don't seem to be able to access the svg in the stop template.

The d3 code works fine outside that table but cant seem to be generated for each element of the table because it can't access the svg element.

```
Template.donutChart.rendered = function() {

//my d3 code is here



     //Width and height
  var w = 300;
  var h = 300;
  var center = w / 2;
  var outerRadius = w / 2;
  var innerRadius = 0;
  var radius = 150;
  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(40)
      .outerRadius(radius + 10 - 25);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) {
          return d.data;
      });


  //Create SVG element  
  var svg = d3.select("#donutChart")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 200 + "," + 100 + ")");

  // GROUP FOR CENTER TEXT
  var center_group = svg.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "ctrGroup")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + "," + (h / 2) + ")");

  // CENTER LABEL
  var pieLabel = center_group.append("svg:text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em").attr("class", "chartLabel")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Clothes")
      .attr("fill", "white");


  Deps.autorun(function() {
      var modifier = {
          fields: {
              value: 1
          }
      };


      Deps.autorun(function() {

          var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
              .data(pie(players))

          var arcOutter = d3.svg.arc()
              .innerRadius(outerRadius - 10)
              .outerRadius(outerRadius);

          var arcPhantom = d3.svg.arc()
              .innerRadius(-180)
              .outerRadius(outerRadius + 180);
          var newGroups =
              arcs
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "arc")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + 150 + "," + 150 + ")")

          //Set up outter arc groups
          var outterArcs = svg.selectAll("g.outter-arc")
              .data(pie(players))
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "outter-arc")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + 150 + ", " + 150 + ")");

          //Set up phantom arc groups
          var phantomArcs = svg.selectAll("g.phantom-arc")
              .data(pie(players))
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "phantom-arc")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + center + ", " + center + ")");


          outterArcs.append("path")
              .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                  return slickColor[i];
              })
              .attr("fill-opacity", 0.85)
              .attr("d", arcOutter).style('stroke', '#0ca7d2')
              .style('stroke-width', 2)


          //Draw phantom arc paths
          phantomArcs.append("path")
              .attr("fill", 'white')
              .attr("fill-opacity", 0.1)
              .attr("d", arcPhantom).style('stroke', '#0ca7d2')
              .style('stroke-width', 5);


          //Draw arc paths
          newGroups
              .append("path")
              .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                  return slickColor[i];
              })
              .attr("d", arc);

          //Labels
          newGroups
              .append("text")

          .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
              })
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text(function(d) {
                  return d.value;
              })
              .style("font-size", function(d) {
                  return 24;
              })



          svg.selectAll("g.phantom-arc")
              .transition()
              .select('path')
              .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                  this._current = this._current || d;
                  var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                  this._current = interpolate(0);
                  return function(t) {
                      return arc(interpolate(t));
                  };
              });


          arcs
              .transition()
              .select('path')
              .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                  this._current = this._current || d;
                  var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                  this._current = interpolate(0);
                  return function(t) {
                      return arc(interpolate(t));
                  };
              });

          arcs
              .transition()
              .select('text')
              .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
              })
              .text(function(d) {
                  return d.value;
              })
              .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                  return textColor[i];
              })

          arcs
              .exit()
              .remove();
      });

  });


    }
```

}

I can't seem to find much information on using d3.js or SVG's within a templates #each wrapper. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I don't seem to be able to access the svg in the stop template"

Comment: as in when I inspect the page inside my stop template the svg div is there but it is empty so I assume my d3 code  var svg = d3.select("#donutChart")  is not able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping your d3 code in a Deps.autorun() function as what's most likely happening is your data isn't available yet when your pie is bound to the data function and thus doesn't render anything.

```
Template.donutChart.rendered = function() {

Tracker.autorun(function () { 

//all d3 code

});

}
```

You look like you're using autoruns further down but not for the bit that gets your data.

Comment: Deps.autorun no longer exist, now we use [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun)